# How to redirect in Xamarin.Forms

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.forms

I use Xamarin and debug on an Android device.
How to redirect an url in Xamarin.Forms?

I'm trying this in default page load.

Comment: see my updated answer for implementation code. You can use it wherever you want, actually, just call this line Device.OpenUri when you need to, for instance when the user clicks a button or when some notification is shown. It depends on your application.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use `Device.OpenUri` to open the URL in the mobile browser:

```
Device.OpenUri(new Uri("http://xamarin.com"));
```

Here is a sample implementation:

```
using System;
using Xamarin.Forms;

namespace Example
{
    class MyPage : ContentPage
    {

        public MyPage()
        {
            Button button = new Button
            {
                Text = "Open URL",
                Font = Font.SystemFontOfSize(NamedSize.Large),
                BorderWidth = 1,
                HorizontalOptions = LayoutOptions.Center,
                VerticalOptions = LayoutOptions.CenterAndExpand
            };
            button.Clicked += OnButtonClicked;

            this.Content = new StackLayout
            {
                Children = {
                    button
                }
            };
        }

        void OnButtonClicked(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            Device.OpenUri(new Uri("http://xamarin.com"));
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: That's C#. I don't think it's possible to redirect from XAML.